# Powershell script to identify the duplicates in list of XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

Experts,

Below is portion of the code where I am trying to find the duplicate line entered in the code.

```
<InputParameters>
    <Parameter Name="Team-Manager" Value="Team-Manager"/>
    <Parameter Name="Team-Lead" Value="Team-Lead"/>
    <Parameter Name="Officer" Value="Y"/>   
    <Parameter Name="Officer" Value="Y"/>               
</InputParameters>
```

Below is my query as per your advise. There is no error but the output is also not returning any result.

```
PS C:\Desktop\Path1\xml> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[count(./Officer) > 1]'

PS C:\Desktop\Path1\xml> 

PS C:\Desktop\Path1\xml> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[count[@Name="Officer"][@Value="Y"] > 1]'

PS C:\Desktop\Path1\xml>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Tag `<age>` is not closed by `</age>` and both `<UNIVERSITY>` tags are also closed wrongly (`</name>` should be `</UNIVERSITY>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath `count()` function to identify `<address>` nodes with more than 1 `<UNIVERSITY>` child node:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//address[count(./UNIVERSITY) > 1]'
```

If `<address>` nodes might validly have multiple *different* `<UNIVERSITY>` entries, use `Group-Object` to test for duplicates:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//address[count(./UNIVERSITY) > 1]' |Where-Object {
    @($_.Node.UNIVERSITY |Group-Object -NoElement |Where-Object Count -gt 1).Count -gt 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

What if there is no proper node field ?  If I want to find a random keyword, can I use it like below ```'//*[count(./UNIVERSITY) > 1]'```

Comment: `//*[count(./UNIVERSITY) > 1]` will find any node(s) that has two `<UNIVERSITY>` nodes as immediate children, yes

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mathias

Comment: @Learning_something_new If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: I tried the same script for a big XML file, but i m getting the invalid token error. Please check and advise where I went wrong this time.

```
PS C:\Desktop\Path1\xml> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//*([@Name="UseCCDT"][@Value="Y"] > 1)'

```
Select-Xml : '//*([@Name="UseCCDT"][@Value="Y"] > 1)' has an invalid token.

Comment: looks like you forgot `count`

Comment: Tried with count, but this time no error and no output too.

Comment: @Learning_something_new please [add the actual details of the question to your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69618436/edit) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238326/discussion-between-learning-something-new-and-mathias-r-jessen).

Comment: Team, Sorry for not following the protocol. I have reposted my query on top of my original post. Please advise.